# automate video capture

Tags: video-processing

I have a bunch of short videos from my digital cam. i know how to convert them to a better codec with ffmpeg but i would also like to make a preview image for the video. Not a thumbnail that window does, something like media player classic which takes about 5-30 shots of the video. I was hoping MPC would be able to do it through cmd line but it doesnt.

What (command line) util can i use to do this or what lib (preferably c/c++)  can i use to generate the images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a programmable automation tool, such as [wintask](http://www.wintask.com/), to do this using your exisiting manual apps.